# How to loop across sheets in an Excel workbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to learn Python and trying to generate a .sql file from a mapping given to me in an excel file. But I am able to go through the rows and columns of the first sheet but unable to move forward to the next sheets. I am using Python 3.7. Each sheet would contain two columns

This is what the excel sheet columns look like:

```
TABLE1                      TABLE2
-----------------------------------
VERSION                      NULL
VALID_FROM                   USG_DT
USERNAME                     MIG
UD_GEPART_ID                 NULL
UD_SEPART_ID                 NULL
```

There can be multiple worksheets in one workbook.

Below is what I have tried so far. Please can someone point me out where I am going wrong in the code as I am not able to move to the next sheet:

```
wb = xl.load_workbook("C:\\New folder\\MAPPING.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheetnames

sheets = [wb.sheetnames]
statement_a = "INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO "
statement_b = "SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(64) */ "


for i, ws in enumerate(sheets):
    stat_c = statement_b 
    stat_d = statement_b + ws[1+i] + " ( "

for sh in wb.worksheets:
    sh = wb.active 
    for col_cells in sh.iter_cols(min_row= 2, min_col= 1, max_col=2):
        for cell in col_cells:
            stat_c = stat_c + str(cell.value) + ", "
    stat_c = stat_c.rstrip(", ")  +" FROM " + ws[1+i] + ";"
    print(stat_c)
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    for col_cellr in sh.iter_cols(max_row = 1,min_col= 2, max_col =2):
        for cell in col_cellr:
            stat_a = statement_a + cell.value + " ( "
    for col_celli in sh.iter_cols(min_row= 2, min_col= 1, max_col=1):
        for cell in col_celli:
            stat_a = stat_a + str(cell.value) + ", "
    stat_a = stat_a.rstrip(", ") + " )"
    print("\n")
    print(stat_a)
```

It does not provide me the correct output. For example it includes the  second sheet name as the table name in select statement of the first worksheet columns. Please can someone help me by pointing out my mistake.

Expected o/p :

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO TABLE1 (VERSION,VALID_FROM,USERNAME,UD_GEPART_ID, UD_SEPART_ID) 
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(64) */ NULL, USG_DT, MIG, NULL,NULL FROM TABLE2;
```

Similarly iterate over the other worksheets and generate statements as above.

Comment: You should show what you expect to see. The code seems to repeat itself, please keep it as simple as possible and avoid mixing `ws[…]` with `ws.iter_cols(…)˚  calls as there is no need for both approaches.

Comment: @CharlieClark: I have added the expected output and I know there would be multiple mistakes as this is my first attempt with python.

Comment: The question title is a bit misleading, hence the answers so far. I guess this really about looping over the cells in columns, right?

Comment: Yes it is about looping over the rows and columns of the worksheets in a workbook

Answer (score 0):

> **sheetnames**
>
> Returns the list of the names of worksheets in this
> workbook.
>
> Type: list of strings

`sheetnames` returns a list. You should change

```
sheets = [wb.sheetnames]
```

to

```
sheets = wb.sheetnames
```

Also below is wrong. You are trying to iterate over each sheet but in the next step you lose sh by assigning it to something else.

```
for sh in wb.worksheets:
    sh = wb.active
```

Comment: I did the suggested changes however when I print the output I still get second sheet name as the table name in select statement of the first worksheet columns.

Comment: Due to `ws[1+i]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should help.

```
target_table, source_table,  = ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=2, min_row=1 max_row=1, values_only)[0]
target_cols, source_cols,  = ws.iter_cols(min_col=1, max_col=2, min_row=3, values)
target_cols.insert(0, "PARALLEL(64)")

stmt = """INSERT INTO {0} ({1})
SELECT {2} FROM {3}.format(target_table, ",".join(target_cols), ",".join(source_cols), source_table)
"""
```

This won't do everything and you'll probably want to adjust it but hopefully it does enough and if not gives you the basis for more specific questions.